# Concatenating strings in a table row from the db

Tags: javascript, php, sql

How do I display the fullname on a table from the firstname and secondname in my database using php or js?

Comment: Hello! Please read [Question Check](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) list and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correct the problem, this is the solution for it:

SQL

```
 SELECT CONCAT(`firstname`, " ", `secondname`) AS `fullname` FROM `users`
```

PHP

```
$fullname = "";
$firstname = "John";
$secondname = "Smith";
$fullname = $firstname . " " . $secondname;
echo $fullname; // John Smith
```

JS

```
var fullname = "";
var firstname = "John";
var secondname = "Smith";
fullname = firstname + " " + secondname;
console.log(fullname); // John Smith
```

Comment: The OP said, "using php or js?".

Comment: Sorry. I corrected myself